# runtime complexities of two While loop

Tags: time-complexity, runtime

I Hope someone Can help me find the

```
public static void Func(int num)
    {
        int x=1,m,y;
        while (x<num)
        {
            x=x+num/10;
            m=num*num*num;  
            y=num;
            while(m>y)
            {
                m=m-100;
                y=y+20;
            }
        
        }   
    }
```

I tried to make a table and give some input and even run with Counter and understand what repeats itself in the code but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

It's O(n^3). The outer loop has a constant number of iterations (~10).
Assume in the inner loop we only have y = y + 1.
The inner loop will have n^3-n iterations. In the question, we advance y by 20 and m by 100. But we don't care about constants in big o.
Thus the answer is O(1) + O(n^3-n) = O(n^3)